# Is it possible to give a list with newline characters as input in Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

I want to know if a list with newline characters can be given as an input in Shiny. Further, want to receive and store in a single vector element.

Input something like a list of IDs.

```
JAR67  
JAR23
JAR40
JAR74
JAR95
JAR50
```

Recive and store in a vector

```
input_ids <- c("JAR67","JAR23","JAR40","JAR74","JAR95","JAR50")
```

I am here after searching all the input templets in R Shiny site. Text box seems promising. I am able to do for a single element input. But not a list with newline characters. Help will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have the list in a file? If so, just import it with `readLines`.

Comment: I know that, saw file as an input. But no, I want to directly input a list with newline characters in a box in the UI itself. Is that possible?

Comment: Maybe `?textAreaInput`.

Comment: Storing as an array or single column matrix not happening.

Comment: Hey Nicola! This worked. Thank you so much :) You can move this comment to answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Nicola in the comment section, I got to this solution.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
 textAreaInput("list","Enter your list")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
 input_ids <- input$list
 input_ids_split <- strsplit(input_ids, "\n")
 input_ids_split <- as.data.frame(input_ids_split)
}
```

Now this `store_list_split` data frame holds a single column list as per my requirement in the question.